# php code doesn`t work on my server (but works fine on on wamp )

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

php code doesn`t work on my server (but works fine on on wamp )
i uploded pages on my server all pages contain php code and run successfully 
only home page dose not work on the server where it run successfully  on my local machine on wamp server
so what can i do ti solve this problem 
the home page on my server

http://opvmmanagement.com/index.php

```
 <?php 
  require_once('admin/lib/projects.php');
  $_project = new Projects();
  $_Projects = $_project->get_all();
  $x = count($_Projects);
  for ($i=0; $i <3 ; $i++) 
  {


    echo '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="item_property">
            <div class="head_property">
              <a href="properties.html">
                <div class="title rent"></div>
                <img src="admin/'.$_Projects[$i]['pimage'].'" alt="Image" width="270" height="202" />
                <h5>'.$_Projects[$i]['pname'].'</h5>
              </a>
            </div>                        
            <div class="info_property">                                  
                <ul>
                    <li><strong>Place </strong><span>'.$_Projects[$i]['pplace'].'</span></li>
                    <li><strong>Price</strong><span>'.$_Projects[$i]['pprice'].'</span></li>
                </ul>                                 
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>';
  }

?>
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Do you get an error? What is the expected behavior and what happens instead?

Comment: no errors only clear page

Comment: I can see that your output is truncated. Turn on php error on your server and see what is causing your scripts to return prematurely. My money is on the `require_once` line, this is failing.

Comment: Typically when your site doesn't transfer over to your server, you either have not fully changed your configuration (if you have one) or (if you weren't using relative paths) your paths might not exist. I would check on those two things.

Comment: i use this on all pages and it`s work only home page does not work

Comment: look i seprate code on other php page and work successfully

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death